# Enforcing unique ranges with Boost interval_map/interval_set

Tags: boost

My data structure needs to host unique ranges (no overlaps) of data, and support data lookup by range. The Boost interval_map/sets seem to be just the thing I need, however, I need to prevent overlaps. What is the most efficient/simple way to ensure non-overlapping ranges with Boost interval_map/sets? For instance, can the container be configured to disallow overlapped ranges on insert?

When inserting a new range, I could loop through the container and check for intersections, or do something like the example given here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/icl/doc/html/boost_icl/examples/overlap_counter.html before each insert, and either accept/reject the insertion, however I think there must be a better way to do this. I have read through the available documentation however could not identify anything interesting.

Help appreciated.